# Run htop over ssh via single command

Tags: linux, ssh, maintenance, htop

I want to run htop over ssh - but launch it automatically on a keyboard-less system with a shell script. My first idea was

```
ssh user@test.home 'htop'
```

but:

```
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Is there any way to start htop remote without typing the command every connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `-t` flag with SSH:

```
ssh user@test.home -t 'htop'
```

This will force a TTY allocation (ssh doesn't allocate a TTY if it's not necessary, normally only for interactive shells).